# c# no Array values

Tags: c#, arrays

```
Array[][,] pos = new Array[1][,];
int posx = rnd.Next(1, 5);
int posy = rnd.Next(1, 5);
pos[0] = new Array[posx, posy];
while (Values.wallpos == pos)
     {
          posx = rnd.Next(1, 5);
          posy = rnd.Next(1, 5);
          pos[0] = new Array[posx, posy];
      }
 Console.WriteLine(posx);
```

So I have this part of my code in which I wanted to generate a random number and assign it to `posx` and `posy`. Basically, coordinates. I was successful in creating something like this in Ruby but I'm kind of new to C# and OOP.

Whenever I run the code, `pos` always shows `System.Array[,][]`.

Essentially, I just need to be able to check if my position is the same with any of the `wallpos` I assigned. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking about here. You say that "pos" always shows something yet your example tries to writeline `posx`, a different variable. Please note that trying to write out a complete array to the console requires you to write loops as simply trying to write out the whole array will write out the *type* of the array, which is likely what you're seeing. Please clarify what the problem is by telling us what the expected output is and what you actually got.

Comment: Instead of using multidimensional arrays, consider wrapping your stuff in separate classes - `class Point{int x; int y;} `

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `Values.wallpos` is an array of 2D arrays. In that case:

```
int[] newPos=new int[2];
do{
    newPos[0]=rnd.Next(1,5); // x
    newPos[1]=rnd.Next(1,5); // y
}while(Values.wallpos.Contains(a => a[0]==newPos[0] && a[1]==newPos[1]));
```